# cannot access second index of multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have this multidimensional array calles 'zones' containing other arrays :

```
[![console.log(Zones)][1]][1]
```

I can access the first array of the multidimensional array with 'array[0]', but the second element of the array is indicated to have a length of 0.
When I access it with 'array[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EXQG.png), it returns '[]' which then contains 6 other arrays.

My problem is that I can't access those arrays. If I log 'array[1][0]', I get 'undefined'.

EDIT : Here are the console logs :

```
 - console.log(zones[0]) : (6) ["Europe", "America", "Africa", "Asia", "Australia", "Atlantic"]
     - console.log(zones[0][0]) : Europe.
     - console.log(zones[1]) : []
    0: (46) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)...]
    1: (20) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)...]
    2: (20) [Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2), Array(2)...]  
etc ...
```

Each of the arrays inside the 5 arrays contained in zones[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EXQG.png) contain two strings.
Here is what I don't understand :

```
console.log(zones[1][0]) : undefined.
```

It should return 5 arrays, each of them containing arrays of two strings.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is quite hard to read.

It looks to me like your array at the start is arr = [array(6), array(0)], which would make

arr[1] = [] and arr[0] = array(6)

arr[1] would have length 0 and so arr[0][1] would be undefined

the other possibility is that your array has the right dimension and I misunderstood the first print, in which case maybe element [1][0] is undefined.

Comment: This is the two start arrays : 
`code`
0: (6) ["Europe", "America", "Africa", "Asia", "Australia", "Atlantic"]
`code`
1: (5) [Array(46), Array(20), Array(77), Array(11), Array(9)]
`code`
What I want and don't manage to do is to access the arrays inside the second array(1).
If I log Array[0][1], I get 'Europe'. If I log array[1], I get '[]', if I log array[1][0] I get 'undefined'.

Comment: @EnyakStew ["Europe", "America", "Africa", "Asia", "Australia", "Atlantic"][1] is not Europe, its America, There has to be something wrong with your arrays

Comment: Sorry I meant [0], not [1].

Comment: So your 2nd array is [Array(46), Array(20), Array(77), Array(11), Array(9)]?
If so, arr[0] is Array(46) but if you go in a console and type Array(46)[1] you will see undefined, were you expecting Array(46) to have content, how was it built?

Comment: It has content. It basically contains arrays, that contains arrays, that contain strings. But I thought I could access those by logging 'Array[1][0][0]', for example, and even that if I were to log 'Array[1][0]', for example, it would return an array,which is contained inside, but instead I get "undefined".

Comment: can you paste the whole code to reproduce the error along with the console logs

Comment: I've added a picture of the console and some console logs.
Thanks.